# If $x^2+5x+p$ and $x^2+3x+q$ have a common factor, then $(p-q)^2=$?

Tags: polynomials

> If $f(x) =x^2 + 5x + p$ and $g(x)= x^2 + 3x + q$ have a common factor, then $(p - q)^2$ = ?

Source: BMA's Talent & Olympiad Class X Maths Ch.2 Q.23, Second Edition 2007

Given answer: $2(3p-5q)$

If you can, solve with almost full steps for I can't figure out the solution in book. I mean that it would be good to include steps enough to understand properly. If you have the book, then to be exact, I didn't understand the last step.

Comment: On the double! ASAP.

Comment: This problem doesn't make sense. With $p=4$ and $q=2$ (and a common factor of $x+1$) we get $(p-q)^2=4$. With $p=6$ and $q=2$ (and a common factor of $x+2$) we get $(p-q)^2=16$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw and in the first case $6p-10q=4$ and in the second case $6p-10q=16$ as required.

Comment: This was my fisrt question so there have some problems regarding spacing. So overlook it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the solution in your book, and depends on noticing that $p-q$ can be put into a simple form first to reduce the algebra involved. If you want a comment on the book solution, you should put the steps in your question so we can see where you are stuck.

If the polynomials have a common factor, they have a common root. Let $x$ be that root. Then eliminate $x$ (which is now a number) as follows:

$$0=f(x)-g(x)=2x+p-q$$ so that $p-q=-2x$ and $(p-q)^2=4x^2$

Now eliminate the term in $x$ from $f$ and $g$ so we get another expression involving $x^2$ by $$0=3f(x)-5g(x)=-2x^2+3p-5q$$ So that $$2x^2=3p-5q$$

Now write the whole thing in terms of $p,q$ as $$(p-q)^2=4x^2=2\cdot 2x^2=2(3p-5q)$$

Comment: Well, it was a misprint in book solution. There wasn't a 5. But still, I'm going to answer my question and specify the book answer as well as the misprint.

Comment: and yes, you have solved it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Let the common factor be x-k
we have,
f(k)=g(k)=0
k<sup>2</sup>+5k+p=k<sup>2</sup>+3k+q
k=(q-p)/2
subtituting "k" in x<sup>2</sup>+5x+p=0
([q-p]/2)<sup>2</sup>+([q-p]/2)+p=0                  {now here was the misprint}
(p-q)<sup>2</sup> = 2(3p-5q)

I think that BMA should reduce the amount of misprints(I don't get it why it's called misprint; should be mistype) in their questions and answers. I saw a + instead of - in factorization question. It was good that I looked explaination and found the mistype.